# What is "fourth-party" in advertisement?

Tags: advertising, tracking, cookie

While I understand [third-party cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Privacy_and_third-party_cookies), I am not sure to understand what exactly "fourth-party" means in sentences such as:

> Third and fourth party ad tracking is allowed on [website] subject to the following guidelines and policies.
>
> Media Company does not have visibility into Agency’s deployment of Fourth-Party Ad Tags
>
> [...] privacy and compliance risks that can come from the use of third and fourth-party ad vendors.

**Question**: In the web advertisement world, what does "fourth-party" usually refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Fourth party refers to any number of script/pixel chains beyond your 3rd party pixel/scripts.  In practice, anytime you add a third party script, that script can then load a another party's script or pixel that can track you.  This is a fourth party ad tracking.

Here's an example from Google and Doubleclick

From https://www.reflectiz.com/the-cybersecurity-effects-of-fourth-parties-on-websites/

> ... as part of your marketing
> efforts, you use an embedded YouTube clip to present your product on
> your website. But did you know that Google installs Double-Click
> pixels on your website? YouTube belongs to Google, and Google uses its
> advertising platform, Double-Click, to monitor who is watching your
> YouTube video.

Answer (score 1):

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/third-party-ads/adx-vendors) cites these examples for what they generally consider as fourth-party:

> The vendors permitted to make **fourth-party calls** are generally of the following type:
>
> - **Research products, which include Analytics/Performance, Brand-Lift Studies, & Verification Services**.

By opposition to third-party:

> The vendors permitted to make **third-party calls** are generally of the following type:
>
> - **Demand Side Platform, Agency Trading Desk, Ad Network, Ad Exchange, Standard Ad Server & Rich Media Vendors**.